# get values from ruby to javascript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Am new to ruby on rails.I want to get the values from ruby to java script.Here is the code iam using.

What i want is i want to create a `data` variable in json format with speed and time values from ruby.Above static values are used

```
 <table border='1' align='center' class="table table-striped" >                         
  <tr>                          
    <th>Id</th>     
    <th>Speed</th>
    <th>Time</th>
  </tr>
<%  @properties.each do |c| %> 
  <tr>
    <td><%= c.device_id %></td>
    <td><%= c.speed %></td>  
    <td><%= c.time %></td>  
  </tr>
<% end %>                   
</table>
```

```
<p><div align='center'>Available Time vs Speed Details are listed below</div> </p>
<div id="bar-demo" align="center">
<script type="text/javascript">
var data = "[[{ 'time': '1', 'speed': '0' }, { 'time': '2', 'speed': '1' }]]
</script></div>
```

Inside javascript can i use ruby code like this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<%  @properties.each do |c| %> 
    var data = "[[{ 'time': 'c.time', 'speed': 'c.speed' }]]
<% end %>        
</script>
```

Also i need to get  data like this(in comma separated form)

```
var data = "[[{ 'time': '1', 'speed': '0' }, { 'time': '2', 'speed': '1' }]]
```

How it is possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this, (not tested)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var data = <%=[@properties.map {|c| {time:c.time, speed:c.speed}}].to_json%>
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

you mean to say `JSON` data. `to_json` returns a JSON string

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Serialization/to_json

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var data = <%= @properties.to_json(:only => [:time, :speed]) %>
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create the method and pass it to .js file -

**html.erb**

```
abc(c.device_id, c.speed, c.time)
```

**JS file**

```
function abc(device_id, speed, time){
   alert(""+device_id)
   alert(""+speed)
   alert(""+time)
 }
```